# Appcelerator Titanium - how I can open a window at a fixed moment of time

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm a newbie in using appcelerator titanium, and I'm using this platform to create an alarm application. But I'm facing with a problem. I don't know how I can open an application's window at a fixed moment of time (even when my application is closed, and the device is sleeping). Have any features as Alarm and BroadcastReceiver as in Android OS? Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On which alarms do yo want to respond?

On iOS you can't wait for such events when your app is in background in general and you can't listen for them with titanium. With Titanium you can use [LocalNotification](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.LocalNotification) (working like a timer). In their callback you should set a property and when the user opens your app you should check this property and open your window.

On Android you may create a background service but i have no idea how to listen on native events (except battery) on android.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I'm finding for a mechanism that has ability to wake up the device when it is sleeping and then open a window in my application. In Android, I know a mechanism called Alarm, I can register an Alarm with the Android OS, and after a specified moment of time (specified when I register Alarm), Android OS would be wake up the device (if it is sleeping) and send an Intend. And then, in my application I can register a BroadcastReceiver that listen for that Intent sent by Android OS. In that BroadcastReceiver, I can do something like start services, open new window (known as Activity in Android).